# How to deploy to Azure an Asp.Net-Core 2.2 Razor Pages App with AzureAD Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm creating a new WebApp using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Razor Pages and I want to authenticate users using AzureAD. This works fine locally with localhost and I can sign in and out with no problem. But when I publish it to azure I can not sign in. After the microsoft sign in pages I am redirected to my WebApp to the page "/.auth/login/done" that says: "You have successfully signed in. Return to the website" and I can return to my website but I am not logged in.

In the App Registration in Azure I have configured the redirect Urls for localhost and for the application. For localhost it looks like "https://localhost:44321/.auth/login/aad/callback" and for the app something like "https://maywebapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback".
I configured the App to use always https to make sure that the Url is the same as the configured in Azure.

This is my Service Configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                 .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = Configuration["Microsoft:Authority"];
                     options.ClientId = Configuration["Microsoft:ClientId"];
                     options.CallbackPath = Configuration["Microsoft:CallbackPath"];
                     options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                     options.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["Microsoft:SignedOutRedirectUri"];
                     options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                 })
                .AddCookie();
```

I expect the same behaviour as when I am running the working App locally.

Answer (score 0):

To make all accesses to pages in this folder be authenticated, we could add the `Authorize` attribute to all page model classes, but we can do better than that. Going back to the Startup class, we can add some Razor Pages conventions to make our lives easier.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account");
            });
    ...
}
```

Here is an [article](https://blog.codingmilitia.com/2019/02/24/aspnet-016-from-zero-to-overkill-authentication-with-identity-and-razor-pages) about authenticate with asp.net razor.

Comment: Hi Joey Cai, thanks for your response :D  but it does not help... I can access to this pages when running locally on my computer. It does not work after deploying to azure. Any idea?